# Remove Pre-installed Apps on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell

I created a Powershell script to set up newly installed Win10 Laptops. First I want to remove all unwanted, pre-installed applications with commands like

```
Get-AppxPackage *onenote* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

What seems to happen is that the application gets deleted but in the start menu, I still have a tile with the OneNote icon. When I click on it, it automatically opens Windows App Store and installs the app without asking.

What is the proper way to remove such applications? I especially want to remove all pre-installed office apps.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-installed appx packages start out as "Provisioned Packages", and get installed for new users when they log in for the first time, even if the app itself has been uninstalled for all users. These can be queried and removed in a similar way:

```sh
# List all the local provisioned packages:
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -online | select displayname

# Example to remove Office appxpp:
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -online |
  Where DisplayName -like "*office*" |
  Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers
```

Note that this will not remove the apps from an existing user's profile if they've already been installed.

I thought the command you were doing already does remove the start menu icon, but if it is just a link to the store now, you'll have to set up a [start menu layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-and-export-start-layout), though it's kind of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

So Removing for `-allusers` is the needed switch here.

```
Get-AppxPackage *microsoft.office.onenote* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

Below are some other options to remove:

```
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.YourPhone* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.ZuneMusic* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.ZuneVideo* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.Xbox* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.WindowsCamera* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.SkypeApp* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.Office.OneNote* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.BingWeather* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.WindowsMaps* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.Messaging* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitareCollection* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.MixedReality.Portal* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.GetHelp* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.People* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

Just don't remove Calculator or Photos. We made that mistake it was hard to get them back for all users.

Comment: Forgot to mention "Provisioned Packages" `$AppxApps = Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online`
`$AppxApps | where-object {$_.packagename –like "*Microsoft.YourPhone*"} | remove-appxprovisionedpackage –online -Verbose` and so on for each package. As mentioned in another answer provisioned means its there and ready for each new user.